# NLog doesn't throw exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I want NLog to throw exceptions and pass to my application whenever database target has a connection failure.

This is my NLog config file:

```
<nlog autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Debug" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
```

Now, it does throw runtime exceptions when config when there is error in config file. Also it does log exceptions about connection failures in internal log file, but it doesn't throw exceptions back to the calling application.

I also tried wrapping Logger.Log method inside a `try-catch` just to be sure that it doesn't swallow it, but the Logger.Log statement is executed successfully.

Is there anything more to it to catch an exception within application. I just want to prepare a cache of the log-events which aren't logged and then log back to the SQL Server when the connection is again available.

**EDIT:**

1. I am using the latest NLog version (v4.0).
2. I have also confirmed that `LogManager.ThrowException` is true at
   run-time too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Write` method of `DatabaseTarget` is wrapped in a try/catch which will only re-throw specific types of exceptions (`StackOverflow`, `ThreadAbort`, `OutOfMemory`, and `NLogConfiguration`). Other exceptions, as you note, will only be written to the internal log.

It would be fairly trivial to implement a [custom target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending-NLog) where you subclass this one and override this method, if that is an option for you.

```
 protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)
 {
    var buckets = SortHelpers.BucketSort(logEvents, c => this.BuildConnectionString(c.LogEvent));

    try
    {
        foreach (var kvp in buckets)
        {
            foreach (AsyncLogEventInfo ev in kvp.Value)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.WriteEventToDatabase(ev.LogEvent);
                    ev.Continuation(null);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    if (exception.MustBeRethrown())
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    // in case of exception, close the connection and report it
                    InternalLogger.Error("Error when writing to database {0}", exception);
                    this.CloseConnection();
                    ev.Continuation(exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!this.KeepConnection)
        {
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```